# Laravel 5.2 dropdown default dynamic

Tags: php, laravel-5

please check the screenshot first. 
[image]

Im trying to edit Product Type name. but when i go to the edit section i want the Product Category of that product should be selected already like we do in html tags eg(`<input value="{{ $productType->product_type_name }}"/>`). So for product type Gold the dropdown menu should show Jewelry instead of showing the first category name(which is food). Also for product Type Wooden, the Product category should show Furniture.  now how should i rewrite the following code so that it doesnt show the first Category name always?

```
{!! Form::select('product_category_id',$CategoryList,null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a drop down list a selected default like this -

```
{!! Form::select('product_category_id',$CategoryList,$productType->product_type_name,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

More information here, https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

Comment: ok i got the hint. it should be 
`{!! Form::select('product_category_id',$CategoryList,$productType->product_category_id ,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`Thank you.. its working @captainquack